# .htaccess rewrite without www AND redirect to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I'd like to redirect

- `www.example.com/*` to `example.com/*`

And **at the same time** redirect

- `example.com/*` to `example.com/forum/*`

But I also have `/wiki/` and `/blog/` and `/style/`, so I **don't want** to redirect

- `example.com/style/*` to `example.com/forum/style/*`

This is what I have at the moment, which is not working quite correctly:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ forum/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Clarification: my question can be asked in a simpler way.

I'd like to redirect an *empty REQUEST_URI* or */*, or a *non-existent file only if it is in the root directory* to **/forum/**.

Comment: This is what I have at the moment, which is not working quite correctly:

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ forum/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: This was never answered.  Did you ever find a way to redirect to forum without ending up at www.example.com instead of just example.com?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wiki|blog|style|forum)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/forum/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: isn't there a way without specifying all the subdirectories?

I currently have only 4, but there will probably be more later...

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would use these rules:

```
# redirect www.example.com to example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# prefix everything but /forum/, /wiki/, /blog/, /style/ with /forum/ and rediret to it
RewriteRule !^(forum|wiki|blog|style)/ /forum%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The second rule could additionally be replaced by this one to check the existence of the first path segment for every request.

```
# check if first segment of requested URI path is either missing
RewriteCond $0 ^$ [OR]
# or cannot be mapped to an existing directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$0/ !-d
RewriteRule ^[^/]* /forum%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this should work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ forum/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^wiki/(.*)$ wiki/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^style/(.*)$ style/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ forum/$1 [L]

RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer for everything but for your **www/no www** problem you could try this :

```
# Enforce www
# If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
# the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /exemple/$1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce NO www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://exemple.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```